# Inorder successor for a BST node: Attribute Error for some nodes

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [Inorder Successor in BST](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/inorder-successor-in-bst/1):

> Given a BST, and a reference to a Node x in the BST. Find the Inorder Successor of the given node in the BST.

Solutions are discussed [at GeeskforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-successor-in-binary-search-tree/), and I looked at the second approach listed there:

> #### Method 2 (Search from root)
>
> Parent pointer is NOT needed in this algorithm. The Algorithm is divided into two cases on the basis of right subtree of the input node being empty or not.

I took this approach, but don't understand why my attempt doesn't work as expected. This is what I tried:

```
def inorder_successor(root, x):
  if x.right != None :
      t = x.right 
      while t.left != None:
        t = t.left
        #print(t.elem)
      return t  
  if root.left == None or root.right:
    return
  if root.left == x:
    return root 

  inorder_successor(root.left, x)
  inorder_successor(root.right, x)
  
def inorder(root):
  if root == None:
    return

  inorder(root.left)
  print(root.elem, end = ' ')
  inorder(root.right)
  
class BTNode:
  def __init__(self, elem):
    self.elem = elem
    self.right = None
    self.left = None

# Create input BST    
n20 = BTNode(20)
n8  = BTNode(8)
n22 = BTNode(22)
n4  = BTNode(4)
n12 = BTNode(12)
n10 = BTNode(10)
n14 = BTNode(14)

n20.left = n8
n20.right = n22

n8.left = n4
n8.right = n12

n12.left = n10
n12.right = n14

print('Given Tree Inorder Traversal: ', end = ' ')
inorder(n20) #Given Tree Inorder Traversal:  4 8 10 12 14 20 22
print()

# This works:
x = n8
print(f'Inorder successor of node {x.elem}: {inorder_successor(n20, x).elem}') #Inorder successor of node 8: 10

# This doesn't work (None). Expected 8
x = n4
print(f'Inorder successor of node {x.elem}: {inorder_successor(n20, x).elem}')  # Error
```

Here is the tree that the above code tries with:

```
     20
    /  \
   8    22
  / \
 4   12
    /  \
  10    14
```

#### Problem

My code is not giving the right output when calling `inorder_successor` for nodes like `n10` or `n4`: it produces an error because the `inorder_successor` function returns `None`.

However, if I print the `n20.elem` in line 11 it works and prints the required node element. So I am confused that this is working, but the code gives an error ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'elem'"). The code works for nodes like `n20` though.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Lacking a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), I am confused what `inorder_successor()` is *supposed* to do: what are those recursive calls about?

Comment: I have attached the problem to the link.  I tried using the recursive calls to transverse the tree nodes.

Comment: (If you want a user notified of a new comment that is not the one who posted, mention their name as in @RodelAdvan.)  Please include in the question the type and the attribute name mentioned in the *attribute error* message. (I still have no idea what the recursive calls in `inorder_successor()` are good for - why would a function to return an inorder successor traverse the tree? Why another traversal in addition to the one in `inorder`?)

Answer (score 0):

The following part of your code has several issues:

```
  if root.left == None or root.right:
    return
  if root.left == x:
    return root 

  inorder_successor(root.left, x)
  inorder_successor(root.right, x)
```

- The `or root.right` part will make the `if` condition true whenever the `root` has a right child, which is always the case in the non-recursive call of your function, and so your function returns `None` in all cases when this part of the code executes (which is when `x` has no right child).
- The only time this logic returns a node is where you have `return root`, and in that case `x` is its left child. But this assumes that if the successor of `x` is not its descendant, then it must be its *immediate* parent of which it must be the left child. This is not generally true. The successor of `x` might be its grand(grand(grand))parent...
- The recursive calls serve no goal, since after having done all the work, your code does not look at what they return
- The fact that this tree is a BST is not exploited in this part of your code. For instance, when `x.elem` is greater than `root.elem`, it makes no sense to look in `root.left` as it is certain that the successor of `x` can only be at the right side.

#### Correction

As you already have pointed to a resource that has provided correct code and explanation, I'll just provide here a solution that maintains the idea of using recursion.

The quoted part of your code can be replaced with this:

```
  if root:
      if x.elem > root.elem:  # must go right:
          return inorder_successor(root.right, x)
      if x.elem < root.elem:  # go left, but root might be the successor
          return inorder_successor(root.left, x) or root
```